# Java Spring Boot in Azure Service Fabric

Tags: java, azure, azure-service-fabric

For deploying a Java Spring Boot REST Service in Azure Service Fabric, do we need a Linux development machine?

Answer (score 1):

I think the **Prerequisites** in the Getting started with Service Fabric with Java [doc](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/resources/samples/service-fabric-java-getting-started/) have answered the question.

The need of Linux development machine depends on the use the Reliable Services API. However the Eclipse Service Fabric plugin is currently not supported on Windows, so it is best to prepare a Linux development environment.

And this is [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-quickstart-java-spring-boot) about deploy Java Service Fabric and how to use [Eclipse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-get-started-eclipse) develop Service Fabric.

If you still have other questions, please let me know.

Comment: Thanks for this info. If we go for AKS in place of Service Fabric, this LINUX dependency exists?

Comment: @Jaish Mathews sry, i haven't used AKS, but You could use VS Code with Azure Dev Spaces to develop Kubernetes. Maybe you could get more details from here.https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/dev-spaces/quickstart-java?toc=%2Fen-us%2Fazure%2Faks%2FTOC.json&bc=%2Fen-us%2Fazure%2Fbread%2Ftoc.json

Answer (score 1):

Reliable Services for Java is not currently supported on windows, this is why they recommend using linux.

If you are not planning to use the Reliable Services, Reliable Collections or Reliable Actors, you can deploy your java application as Guest Executable in windows.

If you want to be future proof, you can wrap your your application in a Container and deploy it on Service Fabric(Own Cluster), Service Fabric Mesh, Docker or Kubernetes, and don't worry about the underlying infrastructure.

Comment: OK. We plan to wrap all our services in docker containers and to deploy in Azure Service Fabric.  If wrap in a docker container, can we still go with windows development ENV, even for Reliable Services?

Comment: You can have your java code running in a windows container on windows, can't have reliable services running on windows or inside a container yet.